# QxOrm giving "could not be resolved" error

Tags: eclipse, qt, qxorm

I am using the Eclipse IDE and Qt plugin.
I am using QxOrm in my Qt project. I have downloaded the library files and compiled them and when I start using the macros it's giving lots and lots of errors like:

```
C_str could not be resolved
macro could not be resolved
string could not be resolved
```

So I tried debugging it and found that, the same errors are also there when I opened the header file in which the macro I was using was defined. What might cause this and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are the exact errors? Can you show us the smallest code sample which gives you these exact errors?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to build all examples from *./test/* directory of QxOrm library package ?
I strongly recommend to test all examples before starting your own project to verify your development environment.

Could you provide please the source code of your persistent class (*.hpp* and *.cpp* files) ?
It will be easier to help you with some code...